# Save Text to speech audio as a wav/mps file to internal flash memory of phone

Tags: java, android, button, text-to-speech

I have read previous posts on here that saves text to speech audio as a wav file to external storage i.e sd card. However i want to save TTS audio as a wav/mp3 file to the internal flash memory of phone and not sd card. This code saves it to external storage but how do i modify it with context.getDir("soundfiles", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); as i have also read only way to save to internal.

```
 public void saveAudio(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.save) {
        String speakTextTxt                  = "Good morning,have a nice day";
        HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, speakTextTxt);

        String exStoragePath                = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File appTmpPath                     = new File(exStoragePath);
        appTmpPath.mkdirs();
        String tempFilename                 = "testing.wav";
        String tempDestFile                 = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + tempFilename;

        tts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "audio saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```